# Can I do this without a marco?

Tags: excel

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
$40/5y 6m
$25/12y
$57/5y
$25/10y
$44/3y, $45.32/3y, $46.68/3y, $48.08/3y, $49.52/3y
$67/5y, $72/5y
$28/5y
```

I need to multiply the dollar amounts by their respective year and sum them if there is more than one.  For example the first row would need to be 40*5.5 and the second to last row would need to be (67*5) + (72*5).  I tried text to columns and a bunch of find and replace, but it was such a messy solution and didn't really work as planned.  So, should I learn how to do macros or is this something that can be done with simple formulas?

Comment: Do you also get "1m", "4m" for 1month, 4 months etc. or is it only whole years and years+"6m"?

Comment: 3m, 4m, 6m, 9m are all present in the dataset

Comment: And the dataset itself is not in Excel, right?

Comment: Then I need to know what each cell holds... Could you put a separator there?

Comment: Each row represents a cell.  I guess the comma could be a separator, right?

Comment: Ah ok, say, cell A1 has the text `$40/5y 6m`

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works:

1) Copy everything into Microsoft Word
2) Open "find and replace" and do the following replacements ("use wildcard characters" should be *unchecked*):
 - replace  (one space) with nothing
Then these have no spaces:
 - replace `$` with `^t`
 - replace `/` with `^t`
 - replace `y,` (with the comma) with `^t^t`
 - replace `y` with `^t`
 - replace `m` with nothing

Now paste this back in an Excel spreadsheet. You should have your data separated in cells like this:
(empty), dollars, years, months, (empty), dollars, years, months, (empty), dollars, years, months...

So then you could just make a partial calculation every 3 cells `=dollars*(years+(months/12))` and then sum these partials into one total.

Would this help?

Comment: Glad to be of help :)